# Scala Akka Actors "dead letters encountered"

Tags: scala, akka

I am testing out my actor system in Scala for a piece of code I'm working on, and I am running into issues when I try to send a message to another actor.

In a watcher class, I am running this code:

```
 val commander = system.actorOf(PocCommander.props)
 commander ! START
```

and in the PocCommander class I have:

```
val poller = context.actorOf(PocPollerCrow.props, name = "poller-crow")
poller ! "start"
```

I can confirm that commander successfully receives the enum START, and when I debug in intelliJ I can see that poller is being created. However, I get this error message:

> [INFO] [07/30/2015 10:26:53.797] [MySpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://MySpec/user/poller-crow] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://MySpec/user/$a#1512757569] to Actor[akka://MySpec/user/poller-crow#-130904114] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.

EDIT: As requested, crow code

```
class PocPollerCrow extends BaseCrow {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "start" => println("yay")
    case _ => println("nay")
  }
object PocPollerCrow {
  val props = Props[PocPollerCrow]
}
```

and commander receive code:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
case START =>
  println("got something yo -> " + START.toString)
  start()
case _ =>
}
```

I also removed the code that shuts down the ActorSystem, so I'm no longer running into this issue. I think the problem was I was sending an actor a message and then shutting down the system too soon after.

Comment: Can you share the code here for both `PocCommander` and `PocPollerCrow`?  Need to see that to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Dead Letters encountered means an actor is sending a message, but no one is there to receive it.  This could be for many reasons but a likely one is that these actors  are sending a message like `sender ! "response"` but since you didn't start them from an actor there is no code to receive the messages.

Comment: Suggest you add the ActorLogging trait and add some log statements to make it easier to follow what is going on. Also add `context.watch(poller)` to the commander and add an entry in the commander's receive method to handler `Terminated(poller)` messages in case your poller is dying for a reason you don't see.